# Laravel 5.4 Redirect back to intended url

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

Im trying to setup the ability to redirect the user to the original intended url.

If a user visits a url and is required to login, it should redirect them to the original url they visited. Ive been doing some reading on Stackoverflow and have come to these solutions, however I cant get it to function as intended (no intended pun :) )

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

I am on Laravel 5.4.36

My `LoginController.php`

```
          if (Auth::attempt($credentials, $remember_me, $user->status == 'Confirmed')) {

              if ($control_panel->auth_throttle == "on") {
                  $this->clearLoginAttempts($request);
              }

              // Added if statement if user is super admin we'll direct to their
              // dashboard
              if ($user->superadmin == true) {

                return redirect()->intended("/admin");

              }
              // if user is not superadmin we'll direct them to their
              // dashboard
              else {
                  return redirect()->intended("v1");    
              }         
          }
```

My `RedirectIfAuthenticated.php`

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
{
    if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {

        return redirect()->intended();

        //return redirect('/admin');
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

Comment: `intended()` uses the '/admin' arg as a fallback URI if it doesn't already have one (that is, the session 'url.intended'). Maybe you should use `redirect()->to('/admin')` to force the superadmin redirect.

Comment: Id like to have either an admin, or a user be directed to the url they had went to prior to logging in.

Comment: If you put a `dd($request->session()->all())` before both return redirects, is there a `session('url.intended')`? And is it the right one?

Answer (score -1):

From my understanding of reading your question, you want to redirect a user BACK to the previous route after authentication?

Laravel has a back helper.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/redirects#creating-redirects